is there any answer to help me by downlaoding pip data
I attempted to run the command pip install -r requirements.txt, but encountered the following error:
yaml
Code kopieren
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.11.0+cu113 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.11.0+cu113

Despite updating everything, the issue persists. Could someone please assist me in resolving this?
I have already consulted various sources, including ChatGPT, and tried multiple solutions, but none have been successful so far.

What is your OS and python version. Most likely your python version is too new for torch 1.11

You probably have to add an extra index for whl as per PyTorch official docs
This might fix the issue
pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113 
